# Microsoft Graph - status code 504 - unknown error, after several requests

Tags: timeout, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-security

I have got a celery scheduling requests to many MS Graph resources after a few hours I get, constantly, the following response:

```
{'error': {'code': 'UnknownError', 'message': '', 'innerError': {'date': '2020-11-27T08:19:26', 'request-id': '714b14e1-e082-4aa9-8ea1-ddc38e84c4b4', 'client-request-id': 'xxx'}}}
```

- This is the real request-id
- I schedule requests every 5' and I avoid overlapped requests of the same resource.
- I've never got a 429, so I have to guess it is not a throttling issue.

Ask for any extra information you need.

Ty in advance.

Comment: (1) What's the Graph API call that you're trying? (2) Outside of your application, can you repro the same issue with Microsoft Graph Explorer or POSTMAN too?

Comment: No, at first it works, this error becomes true after a few hours of execution and it happens in every resource. Here it goes an example "GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/security/alerts?&$top=100". It's nothing about exceeding the requests limit due to I can get a successful response with the same credentials.

Comment: Cool. I dont think you're getting the above error due to limit/throttling. Rather I see that you get HTTP 504, so it's originating from the server for your Graph API call. Check whether you can able to access the security alerts in the portal. If the issue persists for a long time with the above API call, then you may need to consider checking with Microsoft Support.

Comment: I tried the above API and it works for me!!

Comment: I know, as I mentioned it works at first, I can get a successful response right now but, if you keep requesting, it will fail at some point. Actually, I'm waiting for someone from MS to response due to they ask to report errors in StackOverflow ( they actually have responded some reported bugs in StackOverflow ).